# Whats the difference between adding a normal subscriber method to an event, and an anonymous event handler?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I'm struggling to understand why it's okay to attach a 'normal' method as a subscriber to a publisher event, and also a delegate.

For example...

```
public class Caller
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler<RuedaEventArgs> MakeRuedaCall;

    public virtual void OnMakeRuedaCall(RuedaEventArgs args) {
        if (MakeRuedaCall != null) {
            MakeRuedaCall(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my publisher class where I define and raise the event. I'm also making use of some custom event arguments.

```
public class Salsera {
    public Salsera(Caller caller) {
        caller.MakeRuedaCall += MakeMovement;
    }
    public void MakeMovement(object source, RuedaEventArgs args) {
        if (args.CallName == "Vacilala") {
            Turn();
        }
        if (args.CallName == "Patin") {
            MoveToOutside();
        }
    }
    private void MoveToOutside() {
        Console.WriteLine("Ladies move to the outside....");
    }
    private void Turn() {
        Console.WriteLine("Ladies turn....");
    }
}
```

This is a class where I add a method as a subscriber to the event in the constructor.

Suppose I then have somewhere else...

```
Caller matt = new Caller();

EventHandler<RuedaEventArgs> anonyMouseFunc = (sender, eventArgs) =>
{
    switch (eventArgs.CallName) {
        case "Patin":
            Console.WriteLine("Adding a new subscriber for Patin");
            break;
        case "Vacilala":
            Console.WriteLine("Adding a new subscriber for Vacilala");
            break;
    }
};
matt.MakeRuedaCall += anonyMouseFunc;
```

Sorry if this seems like a silly question but why is it that you can subscribe a 'normal' method (assuming it matches the delegate signiture) to an event, and also an anonymous method as a delegate to an event.

i.e. how does `public event EventHandler<RuedaEventArgs> MakeRuedaCall;` handle both options?

Many thanks,

Comment: The `event` handles nothing. It's the compiler who take cares of creating a method and then subscribe it to the delegate of the `event` so when you invoke the `event` the method gets executed.

Comment: Why would you think it would be *different* to add an event handler that has a name vs adding an event handler that doesn't have a name?  How would the existence or lack of a name for the method affect it's ability to be executed when the event fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sorry if this seems like a silly question but why is it that you can subscribe a 'normal' method (assuming it matches the delegate signiture) to an event, and also an anonymous method as a delegate to an event.

You're subscribing a delegate in both cases. In this case:

```
caller.MakeRuedaCall += MakeMovement;
```

... you're using a *method group conversion* to convert `MakeMovement` (which is a method group in spec terminology) into a delegate instance. That code is (almost entirely) equivalent to:

```
caller.MakeRuedaCall += new EventHandler<RuedaEventArgs>(MakeMovement);
```

Or to think of it another way, it's equivalent to:

```
EventHandler<RuedaEventArgs> handler = MakeMovement;
caller.MakeRuedaCall += handler;
```

This ability to create delegates from regular methods isn't just for event handling, of course - you can use it for LINQ and anywhere else you use delegates, too.

Comment: But you didn't tell anything about subscription with anonymous methods, which is (mainly) what OP asks.

Comment: @Evk: The OP appears to understand that the event is subscribed with a delegate in the case of an anonymous method, which is all correct - there's nothing to explain there. They appear to be confused about how the subscription with a method group works, so that's what I explained.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I didn't encounter method groups during my learning but it makes sense now.